# Access named URL parameter in Template or Middleware

Tags: django, django-templates, django-middleware

In my url conf, I have several URL's which have the same named parameter, **user_id**.
Is it possible to access this parameter either in a middleware - so I can generically pass it on to the context_data - or in the template itself?

Sample URL conf to illustrate the question:

```
url(r'^b/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/edit?$', user.edit.EditUser.as_view(), name='user_edit'),
url(r'^b/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/delete?$', user.delete.DeleteUser.as_view(), name='user_delete')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need this data in the template, just override your view's `get_context_data` method:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_id'] = self.kwargs.get('user_id')
        return context
```

Answer (score 14):

For class based views, the `view` is already available in the context, so you dont need to do anything on the view side. In the template, just do the following:

```
{{ view.kwargs.user_id }}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099100/1526703) answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this requires no additional code.

Answer (score 1):

For function based views:

template

```
{% url 'view' PARAM=request.resolver_match.kwargs.PARAM %}
```

views.py

```
def myview(request, PARAM):
    ...
```

Django 2.2