# Access kwargs from a URL in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Can I access value of a named argument (from the URL) in a Django template?

Like can I access the value of `this_name` below from a django template?

```
url(r'^area/(?P<this_name>[\w-]+)/$', views.AreaView.as_view(), name="area_list")
```

I could get the whole URL path and break it up but wanted to check if there's a straight forward way to do that, since it already has a name.

Passing it down in the context data from the view may be an alternative but not sure if I do need to pass it down since I'd guess the template would already have it somehow? Couldn't find a direct method in the [request API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) though.

Comment: this_name will be passed as context and then as it can be used in template. I don't understand why you can't access. Or what other way you want to access it. May be a use case complete will clarify this question

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In the view, you can access the URL `args` and `kwargs` as `self.args` and `self.kwargs`.

```
class MyView(View):
    def my_method(self):
        this_name = self.kwargs['this_name']
```

If you only want to access the value in the template, then you don't need to make any changes in the view. The base [`get_context_data`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/37b2602c895139ff5a44626ed8469c681c438fe4/django/views/generic/base.py#L16) method adds the view to the context as `view`, so you can add the following to your template:

```
{{ view.kwargs.this_name }}
```

Comment: I had to do this for another template that is not based on a class based view but somehow cant figure out how to access kwargs there. Is the method different for non class-based view? Searched in the docs but couldnt find anything useful yet. I tried just `kwargs.this_name` but that also doesnt return anything

Comment: If you have a view function `def my_view(request, myvar, *args **kwargs):` then it's up to you to include the variables in the template context, e.g. `return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'myvar': myvar, 'foo': kwargs.get('foo')})`