# How to save a django "with" template tag value and reuse it in other templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template tag that reads values from the URL. For example
the searched term is cancer. After searching, the next page that appears would have a  with Searched terms: Cancer. And I would like the value cancer to appear in all of my webpages until the user does a new search.

Pages I have work this way:
Search.html > display.html > explore.html

Search.html is where the user enters what they want to search for.

I have a searchedterms.html which is included into all 3 templates and contains the Javascript code to read from the URL.

By using a JavaScript code, I managed to display searched terms: cancer in display.html but in explore.html the value is empty. I want to be able to save "cancer" to the tag and use it in other templates.

```
?conditions=cancer
```

in search.html:

```
<input required="" type="text" name="conditions">
```

in display.html:

```py
{% with searched_terms='searchedterms.html' %}
{% include searched_terms %}
{% endwith %}
```

in explore.html:

```py
{% with searched_terms='searchedterms.html' %}
{% include searched_terms %}
{% endwith %}
```

in searchedterms.html:

```
<div id="searched" class="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  function getUrlParameter(name) {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
      var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
      var results = regex.exec(location.search);
      return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  };
  var condition = getUrlParameter('conditions');

  document.getElementById("searched").innerHTML = "Searched Terms: " + condition;

</script>
```

Actual results: Cancer appears in display.html but not in explore.html. When display.html is refreshed "cancer" also disappears.

Desired Results: Cancer appears in display.html and explore.html until the user starts a new search.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Django Inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) is what you are looking for.

Register your tag in **templatetags** as below:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('searchedterms.html')
def searched_terms(query):
    return {
        'query': query
    }
```

and now in your **searchedterms.html** file:

```html
<div>
your searched query is: {{ query }}  {# display your query here #}
</div>
```

**For Class Based View:**

in your **Search.html** > **display.html** > **explore.html** files:

```
{% load tags %}

{% block content %}

{% searched_terms view.kwargs.conditions %} {# here you pass your kwargs from url #}
<div>some of your existing code. </div>

{% endblock %}
```

how `view.kwargs.conditions` work is explained here [Access kwargs from a URL in a Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098826/access-kwargs-from-a-url-in-a-django-template)

**For Functional View:**
If you want url kwargs in your template from functional views then you can get url kwargs in view and pass it as context data:

```
def search_view(request, **kwargs):
    """
    your existing codes
    """
    context = {'conditions': kwargs.get('conditions')}
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

**Using `request` in the template to access from url:**
If you want to access the data from url in template then you can also use `request.GET` or `request.POST` based on how you want to access the data as in your **Search.html** > **display.html** > **explore.html** files:

```
{% load tags %}

{% block content %}

{% searched_terms request.GET.conditions %} {# here you access data from url #}
<div>some of your existing code. </div>

{% endblock %}
```

you can look for django documentation [HttpRequest objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) for what you can have access with `request`.

Comment: Does it work for function based views? From the link you sent it seems like ```view.kwargs.conditions``` only works for class-based views.

Comment: I don't think `view.kwargs.` is possible in functional views but you can pass your context data to template from functional view as `return render(request, 'search.html', {'myvar': myvar, 'conditions': kwargs.get('conditions')})`

Comment: If you are still searching for a solution then I think my updated answer may be handy.

Comment: Hi, I tried your updated answer, however i got these error instead ```searched_terms received too many positional arguments```

Comment: In my end, there isn't any problem it's working as expected. Hope you may have done something wrong. Try to capture those arguments with `*args` in template tags and print those `args` to check what are those many arguments.