# How do I access Django URL parameter /<thing>/ in HTML template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

```py
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', include('Homepage.urls')),
url(r'^RepairLog/', include('RepairLog.urls')),
url(r'^RepairLog/DMRView/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="RepairLog/DMRView.html"),name="dmr view"),
url(r'^RepairLog/DMRtab/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="RepairLog/DMRtab.html"),name="dmrtab"),
url(r'^RepairLog/DMRwork/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="RepairLog/DMRwork.html"),name="dmrwork"),
url(r'^Inventory/', include('Inventory.urls')),
url(r'^Inventory/inventory/<barcodething>/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/inventory.html"),name="inventory"),
url(r'^Inventory/inventory/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/inventory.html"),name="inventory"),
url(r'^Inventory/createitem/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/createItem.html"),name="createitem"),
url(r'^Inventory/manageitem/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/manageItem.html"),name="manageitem"),
url('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),] ##Necessary to login validation
```

I am trying to access **barcodething** in my inventory.html template.
I have tried `{{barcodething}}` but that does not work.
URL I am using is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Inventory/inventory/123456789/` which should pass `barcodething=123456789`

If I delete `url(r'^Inventory/inventory/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/inventory.html"),name="inventory"),`
Or change it to:
`url(r'^Inventory/inventory/**$**', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/inventory.html"),name="inventory"),`

Then this error unexpectedly comes up which may be helpful in determing root cause:

`

```
 Using the URLconf defined in MT.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    ^ ^homepage/ [name='homepage']
^RepairLog/
^RepairLog/DMRView/ [name='dmr view']
^RepairLog/DMRtab/ [name='dmrtab']
^RepairLog/DMRwork/ [name='dmrwork']
^Inventory/ ^items/$ [name='item-list']
^Inventory/ ^items\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='item-list']
^Inventory/ ^items/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='item-detail']
^Inventory/ ^items/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='item-detail']
^Inventory/ ^itemreorder/$ [name='item-list']
^Inventory/ ^itemreorder\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='item-list']
^Inventory/ ^itemreorder/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='item-detail']
^Inventory/ ^itemreorder/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='item-detail']
^Inventory/ ^$ [name='api-root']
^Inventory/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
^Inventory/inventory/<barcodething>/$ [name='inventory']
^Inventory/createitem/ [name='createitem']
^Inventory/manageitem/ [name='manageitem']
accounts/
The current path, Inventory/inventory/1/, didn't match any of these.`
```

Solution:
Change
`url(r'^Inventory/inventory/<barcodething>/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/inventory.html"),name="inventory"),`

TO:
`url(r'^Inventory/inventory/(?P<barcodething>[\w-]+)/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/inventory.html"),name="inventory"),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
{{ view.kwargs.barcodething }}
```

Here is more detailed answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099100/11449888

Comment: Hi HelenShy, I tried that and it did not produce any information for me.
I have also tried {{request.resolver_match.kwargs.barcodething}}
And also {{self.kwargs.barcodething}}
And even <li><a href = "{% url 'Inventory:inventory' barcodething %}">{{barcodething}}</a></li>
I must be missing something else.

Comment: If I delete `url(r'^Inventory/inventory/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="Inventory/inventory.html"),name="inventory"),
`code (or add a $ at the end of the regex) then Django fails to find the path. I think this may be the root cause. 
`Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Inventory/inventory/1/
Using the URLconf defined in MT.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

The current path, Inventory/inventory/1/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Have you tried changing definition in url? r'^Inventory/inventory/?P<barcodething>[\w-]+)/

Comment: Excellent @HelenShy! `r'^Inventory/inventory/**(**?P<barcodething>[\w-]+)/ `worked with `{{barcodething}}` in my template!!

Comment: Congratulations!)) You need to use regex when you are defining slugs in url...

Answer (score 0):

You can also access URLs and match patterns with django's [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

`{% url 'name_of_url_defined_in_pattern' <pattern> %}`